# Notice: Undefined variable: template & Fatal error: Call to a member function writePage() on a non-object

Tags: php

I have a problem. When I run my site, the template error errors.

I get these two errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: template in /home/us22368/domains/******.nl/public_html/index.php on line 4 
Fatal error: Call to a member function writePage() on a non-object in /home/us22368/domains/******.nl/public_html/index.php on line 4
```

Some code:

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once('global.php');
$template->writePage('index');
$template->echoPage();
?>
```

My global.php includes this class (class.template.php) :

```
<?php
if (!class_exists('template')) {
    class template {
        public $template;
        public function writePage($pageName) {
            $file = 'app/themes/' . THEME . '/' . $pageName . '.html';
            if(!file_exists($file)) {
                die('The Page You Asked for does not exist.');
            } else {
            $this->content .= file_get_contents($file);
            }
        }
        public function echoPage() {
            echo $this->content;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: You have to create an instance of template like `$template = new template();`

Comment: you are not initializing `$template` `$template=new template();` before using any template class function

Comment: Then I get this error:
`Notice: Undefined property: template::$content in /home/us22368/domains/******.nl/public_html/app/includes/classes/class.template.php on line 11`

Comment: In your template class add a 'content' property.

Comment: `public $content;` under `public $template;` as @ChoiZ says. You are using `$this->content` meaning that this class should a `content` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index.php file you have to create an instance of template class:

```
<?php
require_once('global.php');
$template = new template();
$template->writePage('index');
$template->echoPage();
?>
```

Take a look to php documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php